# Wordpress API and Angular cross origin policy violation

Tags: php, angular, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I know there's a lot of topics on this issue here but nothing seems to help.
I've got an Angular 7 app running on `http://localhost:4201` and a Wordpress site
with REST API enabled. If I call `http://appsite.com:8080/wp-json/` (which is actually also a local server running on OpenServer) I get a huge JSON with all the information of my site, so I'm sure the API works. 
But when I try to call this url from my Angular app I always get this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://appsite.com:8080/wp-json/' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:4201' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I've got this hook in y wordpress's functions.php

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );
    add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
        return $value;
    });
}, 15 );
```

But it doesn't work. I even tried to call this `header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );`
in index.php

What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem has resolved after I cleared browser cache.